# Unable to upload app bundle to APS Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm following the postman instructions and I'm stuck on [Task 4 Upload AppBundle](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-tutorial-postman/blob/master/DA4Revit/instructions/task-4.md).

The downloaded postman files. I checked the github documentation and it does not list the authorization in the header. When I click send I get the error below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.</Message>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>        <HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

When I add the authorization to the header I get the error below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have checked that my authorization token is still active. The example files don't list the authorization in the header, but I've included it in the header

[image]

The variables in the Body of the request seem fine
[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get `Register the AppBundle` succeeded before doing "Upload the AppBundle"?

Comment: Yes, I was able to successfully register the AppBundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the error:**

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
    <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
    <ArgumentValue>Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ArgumentValue>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId
    <HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

You should not be adding APS auth headers to the call in `Upload the AppBundle` step. The call is to AWS S3 service where you are uploading this bundle.

---

**For the error:**

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.</Message>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

You have to execute the `Upload the AppBundle` before the link you got from the previous step `Register the AppBundle` expires.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback wrt to the AWS comment. I did register the AppBundle prior and was successful, but I wasn't able to upload it. I ran through all the steps again this morning and it worked this time around.